# Error when importing ethers from hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I am creating a react frontend that interacts with some smart contracts. However, when I run npm start to run my react application, I am getting the following error:

**Failed to compile.**

```
./node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/ArgumentsParser.js 166:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (166:26)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|         throw new errors_1.HardhatError(errors_list_1.ERRORS.ARGUMENTS.MISSING_TASK_ARGUMENT, {      
|           param: ArgumentsParser.paramNameToCLA(paramName),
>           task: taskName ?? "help"
|         });
|       } // We only parse the arguments of non-subtasks, and those only
```

After doing some debugging, I noticed the error is introduced at the line in my interact.js file(the file that has all my contract interaction functions) where I import ethers from hardhat in order to do some contract interaction :

```
import { ethers } from 'hardhat';
```

Would anyone know how I can sold this problem?

Comment: how did you solve that problem ?

Comment: have you fixed?

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to `package.json` In your React project. Locate “react scripts” and change it to 4.0.1, save it and in your react project in terminal hit `npm install`. Restart and check npm start again. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. I tried it out but I'm still getting the same error, any alternative you'd suggest I attempt?